# jruby on rails with tomcat deploying a war file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jruby, jrubyonrails

I'm using jruby with rails and want to deploy a small application in tomcat7. I used the warbler gem to create war file. The application is relConnections and the war file created is relConnections.war. I started the tomcat server running startup.bat file.

Let me know what are the steps to be followed so that i can open

```
htpp://localhost:8080/rconnections/modify
```

`modify` is my view and `rconnections` is my controller which is in the `relConnections` folder and also in the `relConnections.war` file.

I already tried copying the war file into the webapps folder in tomcat. I was not able to understand what was happening. I could not open my application.
Any kind of link in the net would also be helpful. Thanks

Comment: I once wrote a longer answer concerning deployment on tomcat - http://stackoverflow.com/a/11108680/498226 - does this help?

Comment: @Florian Thank you, but now my manager suggested not to use tomcat because of all the headache. Now i'm using mongrel and i'm happy

Comment: Great - in my experience tomcat can be a pain to setup, but it's pretty smooth after it runs. And the deployment process is really nice, especially if you need other people to do it :D

Comment: @Florian i will definitely give it a try once this project is done